# How to use dependency injection for transient instances in async tasks loop

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, worker-service

There is a class that implements an interface called SomethingManager.cs
like:

```
 public class SomethingManager : ISomethingManager
```

This is a worker service in .net 6 and there is another class library project in the same solution that contains the interface and implementation of SomethingManager.
Dependencies are being registered in the worker service project like

```
      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                //AddSingleton or Transient here?
                services.AddSingleton<ISomethingManager, SomethingManager>();
                ...
```

The problem is that, in the entrypoint project that works in an async way,there is a loop like:

```
       foreach (xml in xmls)
            {
                tasks.Add(StartProcessAsync(xml));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Inside StartProcessAsync it uses SomethingManager instance hat was previously registered and injected in the constructor.
The problem is that the class SomethingManager has some private members that are supposed to be unique for every task and I noticed that in this way it causes fatal errors between the tasks.Actualy this class needs to share a sessionId that a method .Connect() is giving the value every time.We have to call .Connect() method, one time before other actions,inside every task.

So,
My question is how can I register the SomethingManager with Dependency Injection and every task that uses this instance (which is registered with DI) to have different values for its private members?
And, if can't do it in this way, am I supposed to create new instance for this every time?

```
  public Task StartProcessAsync(xmlFileInfo xml)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //this one doesn't work inside tasks loop it cases problems because
            //the sessionId that contains has to be different for every task
            //_somethingManager.DoSomething();
            //Like this?
            var somethingManager= SomethingManager(_someSettings);
            somethingManager.DoSomething();
            var mem = somethingManager.ThePrivateMember; 
            //another object which has also private members in the same class.
         });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should register that as Transient yes. You talk about SomethingManager and SomethingService. Typo and its the same thing or did you miss telling something that might be relevant?

Comment: No it is just a typo.SomethingManager is the problem that tasks are using the same instance but every task creates a new value for SessionId.But I also used AddTransient but it didn't work also

Comment: Personally I would register `SomethingManager` as scoped and create scope manually for every task run.

Comment: @GuruStron Sound logical.Can you help me with this way?

Comment: Register a factory method that returns an `ISomethingManager`, and make the `SomethingManager` registration `Transient`.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas Without having full overview of your code infrastructure it is hard to guess what would be optimal way to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: Ok, until now your comments helped me a lot.I will answer my own question when I have the solution.Thank you!